# Return the value in same row if specific text exists with a range of cells

Tags: vlookup

I am looking for a way to scan a range of cells for specific text, and if that text exists within that range, display the corresponding value in the same row within another range of cells

I have Sheet1! with columns A:K. In cell A1, I want to display the value in Column B, if columns G:K contain "Mark"

So, Say H29 contains "Mark". I want to return the value in B29.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, enter this formula in A1:

```
=index(IF(G1:G&H1:H&I1:I&J1:J&K1:K="mark",B1:B,))
```

[image: mark]